# Print statement displaying only the first account name on the list

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, for-loop

To be clearer, I've pasted the full code. My question is on the "withdrawal()" function. The account.name variable in the second print statement shows only the first account name on the list despite the loop being on a different account name

```
def validation(accounts):
    pin = int(input("Enter 4 digits pin: "))
    for account in accounts:
        if pin == account.pin and len(str(pin)) == 4:
            print("\nWelcome! {}, your account balance is ${}".format(account.name, account.balance))
            return withdrawal(accounts)
    print("\nInvalid pin.\n")
    return try_again(accounts)

            
def withdrawal(accounts):
    amount = int(input("\nEnter amount to withdraw: "))
    for account in accounts:
        if account.balance > amount:
            account.balance -= amount
            print("\nTransaction successful, your new balance is ${}".format(account.balance))
            new = input("\nNew transaction? YES/NO?: ")
            if new.lower() == "yes":
                return withdrawal(accounts)
            print("\nTake your card {}. Thank you for banking with us.".format(account.name))
            break
    else:
        print("\nTransaction failed due to insufficient funds.")
                    
    
def try_again(accounts):
    re_enter = input("Enter YES to try again or NO to exit: ")
    if re_enter.lower() == "yes":
        return "\n" + validation(accounts)
    elif re_enter.lower() == "no":
        print("\nGoodbye. Take your card.")
    else:
        print("\nInvalid input. Take your card.")
    
        
class Account:
    def __init__(self, name, pin, balance):
        self.name = name
        self.pin = pin
        self.balance = balance
        

accounts = [Account("Bryan Somto", 4289, 300000), Account("Dubem Vic", 3329, 250000), Account("Munz Gee", 2200, 220000)]


validation(accounts)
```

Comment: what does the variable `accounts` means? it raise an Error on this line. plz provide the full example

Comment: Indenting it one level deeper, prints the statement for all the account in my accounts variable (i.e. "Transaction failed due to insufficient funds." * Number of account in accounts).

Comment: I have put up the full code for clarity. Yossi Levi

Comment: first, you haven't pasted your full code, account class isn't here. but I created a dummy one, and the problem is that you just `break` after the first print, therefore the loop is terminated. remove it or call `continue` instead

Comment: Kindly check again. Account class is located after all my functions. Using continue doesn't help either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Summary

Simply put, it's because every time the `withdrawal` function is called, it iterates through all the accounts, and does the transaction with the first account that has a high enough balance. As "Bryan Somto" is the first account, the transaction always happens with that account. Modify the `withdrawal` function to only take in the specific account to do the transaction with.

### Explanation

When you call the `withdrawal` function, you should instead only pass the specific account where the user is doing the transaction. So, instead of calling `withdrawal(accounts)`, call `withdrawal(account)`. Then only that specific account is passed to the function.

```py
def withdrawal(account):
    amount = int(input("\nEnter amount to withdraw: "))
    if account.balance > amount:
        account.balance -= amount
        print("\nTransaction successful, your new balance is ${}".format(account.balance))
        
        # New transaction
        new = input("\nNew transaction? YES/NO?: ")
        if new.lower() == "yes":
            return withdrawal(account)
        
        print("\nTake your card {}. Thank you for banking with us.".format(account.name))
    else:
        print("\nTransaction failed due to insufficient funds.")
```

Here, the `withdrawal` function only deals with the specific account.

It would be best if you also modify your `validation` function. Because currently, it won't work if multiple people have the same PIN.
It should first take in the account holder's name, and then the PIN. Then it should check if the two match up.

So like this:

```py
def validation(accounts):
    name = input("Enter your name: ")
    for account in accounts:
        # Checking account name
        if account.name == name:
            pin = int(input("Enter 4 digits PIN: "))
            
            # Checking PIN length
            if len(str(pin)) != 4:
                print("\nInvalid PIN.\n")
                return try_again(accounts)
            
            # Checking PIN
            if account.pin == pin:
                print("\nWelcome! {}, your account balance is ${}".format(account.name, account.balance))
                return withdrawal(account)
            else:
                print("\nThe PIN is incorrect")
                return try_again(accounts)
    else:
        print("\nThere is no account with that name.")
        return try_again(accounts)
```

Here it also only checks the length of the pin once. In the original code, it checks the length every time, and that's unnecessary.

In the first `if` block of the `try_again` function, it would be better if you change `return "\n" + validation(accounts)` to `return validation(accounts)`.
You don't need that newline character, and it could cause bugs down the road.

### Aside

Regarding checking the account name:

The standard practice is to use an account number/ID that will definitely be unique, then even if two people have the same name, it will still work. It's also better because it's generally easier to type in an account number instead of typing in a long name. In this one, if two people have the same name, it will go with the one that is first in the `accounts` list, and will never get to the second one.